# Display selected records as pdf in a new tab

Tags: apex, visualforce

On Account page i have a button which on click will display a vf page with its related opportunities with checkbox.

I want on selected records which i click generate pdf, it will display those records in a pdf format.

controller

```
public class OppControllerr {

Private Id accID;

public OppControllerr(){

accID=  ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('acId');
refresh();
}
public List<OppWrapper> myList = new List<OppWrapper>();

    public PageReference refresh()
    {
        myList.clear();
        for(Account a : [select id, name, (select name from opportunities) from Account where id= : accID])
        {
            for(Opportunity opp : a.Opportunities)
                myList.add(new OppWrapper(false, opp));
        }
        return null;
    }

    public List<OppWrapper> getMyList()
    {
        System.debug('count'+myList.size());
        return myList;}

  public class OppWrapper {
    public Boolean selected{get;set;}
    public Opportunity opp{get;set;}
    public OppWrapper(Boolean selected1, Opportunity opp1)
    {
        selected = selected1;
        opp = opp1;
    }

}

}
```

vf page -

```
<apex:page controller="OppControllerr">
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock >
<apex:pageBlockSection >
<apex:pageBlockTable id="oppList" value="{!myList}" var="o">
 <apex:column >
        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!o.selected}" />
    </apex:column>
<apex:column value="{!o.opp.Name}"/>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
<apex:commandButton value="Generate PDF"/>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can achieve it easily using apexCookies
here is the sample working code for this

```
PageReference pg = page.testPdf;
        list<account> accList = [select id, name from account limit 1000];
        string str = '';
        for(account acc : accList){
            str += acc.id + ',';
        }
        Cookie counter = new Cookie('rishi', str ,null,-1,false);
        pg.setCookies(new Cookie[]{counter});
        return pg;
```

It will have comma seprated ids of account stored in variable rishi

Now in the constructor of your pdf get cookies

```
str = ApexPages.currentPage().getCookies().get('rishi').getValue();
        list<string> temp = new list<string>();
        temp = str.split(',');
        accList = [select id, name from account where id in : temp ];
```

Please mark if your query is resolved otherwise let me know your bloackages